# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

Tags: java, string-length, charat

I'm trying to print the last name character, but my code is generating an exception.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastCharacter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type your name: ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();
        char nameLastChar = lastCharacter(name);
        System.out.println("Last character = " + nameLastChar);


    }


    public static char lastCharacter(String text){

        int last = text.length();
        char lastChar = text.charAt(last);
        return lastChar;
    }


}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

I can't find my mistake and I don't understand the exception information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a String is 7 characters long, the last index is 6, not 7. Remember, indexing starts at 0.

You want

```
int last = text.length() - 1; // Adjust the index
char lastChar = text.charAt(last);
```

Comment: Maaaan thanks a lot :) Now I understand exception message. Have a godd day and thanks once again :)

Comment: @Kempa please be corteus and mark this answer as correct.